# What is the IEEE style for a translated quotation?

Tags: citation-style, ieee, quotation

I am writing my thesis in french but most of the references I have are in english.

Sometimes, I would like to  incorporate a direct quotation into a sentence but since my text is in another language, I usually do a literal translation (because I don't want to change the author's words). In this case, what IEEE's style should I use?

Comment: Which institution is the thesis being submitted to? what are their formatting / style / referencing standards?

Comment: @SolarMike I am not sure that 'thesis' is the right word in my case, maybe 'dissertation' is more appropriate (or maybe it is the same thing, I don't know). I just need to send it to my school and I can use the formatting style that I want. But since I decided to use the IEEE's one I would like to stick with it.

Answer (score 1):

IEEE is based on the Chicago Style, so whenever you do not find any guidance directly from the IEEE, it is best to consult the Chicago Style Manual. In Chapter 11 of the Chicao Style Manual, titled "Quotations and Dialogue", you can find some relevant directives. For instance:

- First, make sure your audience really needs a translation from
  English sources; if you audience is an academic one consisting of
  researchers who perhaps publish themselves in international journals,
  then I am not sure whether translations are really necessary:
  'Whether to provide translations of quoted passages depends on the
  linguistic abilities of the likely readers' (11.86).
- Second, you can simply quote the sentence in your translated version (in the usual form you use to quote another source), but consider putting the original text into a note
  (11.88): 'In many works, quotations from a foreign-language source
  need appear only in translation. Should the original be necessary, it
  can be placed in a note.'
- Third, credit the translation to a published source of the
  translation with all bibliographical details. If such a source does
  not exist, then the Chicago Manual (11.89) states: 'Authors providing
  their own translations should so state, in parentheses following the
  translation, in a note, or in the prefatory material—for example, “My
  translation” or “Unless otherwise noted, all translations are my
  own.”'